# How a pendulum accelerates?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram, oscillators

I have learned that $-g\sin\theta$ describes the acceleration of a pendulum. But surely if a pendulum is held from a point, say this point is $a$ and another point $b$ and say suppose that point $a$ is higher than point $b$, upon dropping the whatever object is attached to the pendulum, and within both scenarios, each ball must stop at a given point, and this point is the same for whatever point they are dropped from, say, point $c$, therefore dropping the ball from point A must ultimately accelerate more than point B since it is under influence longer from gravity.

So I figured, $-g\sin\theta = a$ ( sorry for the ambiguity, here $a$ is acceleration of course ), doesn't necessarily work in this case. Could we view the pendulum motion as individual discrete gains in energy due to gravity and then integrate it to achieve the accumulated energy at point b?

So perhaps something like,

$$\int_a^c -mg\sin\theta d\theta$$

Comment: If you pull the pendulum end up higher, of course it reaches a higher speed by the time it reaches the bottom. This is because you constructively integrate the force over a longer distance. I don't see how this changes the accuracy of the original statement of acceleration.

Comment: I don't fully understand the confusion. $-g\sin\theta$ is just the tangential acceleration component. It's not the entire acceleration. I'm not sure I understand how this equation contradicts the scenarios you outline as well. Perhaps you are not realizing the acceleration is a function of $\theta$ that changes over time and depends on the position of the mass?

Comment: Well I didn't think the original equation of acceleration would apply here because if point c, was at some value theta, then -gsin(theta) would be the same acceleration regardless of whether or not the pendulum dropped at point a or b, which doesn't make sense because if the pendulum dropped at point a, then it must have a higher acceleration than otherwise. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: @BioPhysicist That cleared up some confusion. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @MikeFernandez Oh, so you think that because the object is moving faster that it must have a larger acceleration at the same point in space? This isn't a stupid question btw.

Comment: Yeah. Is that not correct? @BioPhysicist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangential acceleration of the mass is solely determined by it's angular position $\theta$ by what you say: $a_\bot=-g\sin\theta$. There is no velocity dependent forces in the scenario you describe, so the acceleration will not depend on the velocity as well.

If an object is released from rest at $\theta_A$ and another object is released from rest at $\theta_B<\theta_A$, then when mass $A$ reaches $\theta_B$ it will indeed have a larger velocity than mass $B$ at $\theta_B$, but they both will have the same tangential acceleration at $\theta_B$ because the tangential acceleration is a function only of $\theta$.

A simpler example of this is a ball that is dropped from your hand versus one that is thrown from your other hand. Once both balls are released they will have the same acceleration ($g$ downwards) even though their velocities are different.

The more general misunderstanding here is that a larger velocity means a larger acceleration must have caused that larger velocity. But this is not the case. Velocity changes over time due to acceleration, so "small" accelerations can cause "large" velocities and vice versa, but it is incorrect to assume that at some instant a large velocity means a large acceleration, or that the acceleration is solely, if at all, determined by the velocity.

Comment: I'm not sure why I thought the acceleration would be any more or less than a static value. Thanks, this makes it far more clear.

Comment: This may be better dedicated to a separate question, but given that acceleration is static, and rightfully so in this circumstance, integrating acceleration ( which yields velocity ) at these two given points implies they ALSO have the same velocity which doesn't make any sense. What gives?

Comment: @MikeFernandez The acceleration changes over time because $\theta$ changes over time. Additionally they are starting at different angles. The time integrals of the accelerations will not be equal.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks.

Comment: Yes the key point is that the acceleration is NOT constant.  Indeed for small angles this is like a spring-mass system and clearly $a$ is not constant as periodic motion is not of the form $\theta_0+\omega_0 t +\frac{1}{2}\alpha t^2$.